# What is wrong with this code? How can i correct it?

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm completely new to PHP. So yeah this code might totally make no sense. But anways. I want to ask for help. If someone can tell me what is wrong and or just write correct code.

Basicly what i try make code to do is check if user is logged in, if not then show he login and register link.

If he is logged in then show him his username.

Here is PHP code:

```
<?php

    require("common.php");

    if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        echo("<a href="login.html"><b>Login</b></a>");
        echo("<a>or<a>");
        echo("<a href="register.html"><b>Register</b></a>");
    }

    else
    {
        echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
    }
?>
```

Code from HTML:(Code that i use to include this code. Not sure if its also...)

```
<header action="php/check.php" method="post">
```

**Thanks for answers** Still not working tho :(
Here is current code, I edited how you guys adviced.

```
<?php
    session_start()

    require("common.php");

    if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        echo '<a href="login.html"><b>Login</b></a>';
        echo '<a>or<a>';
        echo '<a href="register.html"><b>Register</b></a>';
    }

    else
    {
        echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->username . "\n";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where is your `session_start()`?

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: echo doesn't need the parenthesis

Comment: `"<a href=\"login.html\"><b>Login</b></a>"` escape quotes.

Comment: I don't think you need the `$_SESSION['user']` if you have `$current_user->user_login`. Or vice versa.

Comment: `<header action="php/check.php" method="post">` **header** action? I never saw that before. Don't you mean `<form action="php/check.php" method="post">` **<form...**? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure session are starting automatically? 
Otherwise you need to add this:

Edit: And also remove the parentethis around echo, it's built-in the language, it's not a function. And escape quotes as well.

```
<?php
    session_start()

    require("common.php");

    if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        echo "<a href=\"login.html\"><b>Login</b></a>";
        echo "<a>or<a>";
        echo "<a href=\"register.html\"><b>Register</b></a>";
    }

    else
    {
        echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n";
    }
?>
```

You can also add a php.ini and use session auto_start.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
{
    echo '<a href="login.html"><b>Login</b></a>';
    echo ' or ';
    echo '<a href="register.html"><b>Register</b></a>';
}
```

Comment: Thank everyone for anwers. Still is not working tho :(

Currently looks like this
<?php
 session_start()

 require("common.php");
    
    if(empty($_SESSION['user']))
    {
  echo '<a href="login.html"><b>Login</b></a>';
  echo '<a>or<a>';
  echo '<a href="register.html"><b>Register</b></a>';
 }
 
 else
 {
  echo 'Username: ' . $current_user->username . "\n";
 }
?>

Comment: But are you calling session_start() also when setting the $_SESSION?

Comment: Yes. Common.php have session_start() at end of it.
i also tried it with manually writing session_start().

Comment: I think you probably have `error_reporting` turned off. Looks like you miss a semicolon after `session_start()`, if that's not a typo in the comment..

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to escape the double quotations in all the escape statements as this:

```
echo "<a href=\"login.html\"><b>Login</b></a>";
echo "<a>or<a>";
echo "<a href=\"register.html\"><b>Register</b></a>";
```

You don't need the parentheses for `echo`.

Second, in order to use the `$_SESSION` variable, you need to start the session before that using the function `session_start()`.

Comment: I did that. Still not working. I was wondering do i need some html on php file. or php to html?

so currently my HTML file have:
<header action="php/check.php" method="post"> </header>

So im trying to print that php file answers to header...
At this moment it won't print it anywhere.

Comment: did u give the file path correctly? `action="php/check.php"` is relative to the current location. Use a `/` before it. It goes like `action="/php/check.php"`.  If it doesn't work, take a look at this to get the root's location: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17036192/when-new-page-is-created-the-css-is-not-taken-into-account/17036267#17036267

Comment: @user2475515 I've never seen `<header action="php/check.php" method="post"> </header>` before. `<form action...</form>` yes, but *header*?

Comment: @Fred How did I not notice it? -_-

Comment: I made it to 
<form action="php/check.php" method="post">
</form>

Still not working tho :(

Comment: @user2475515 The easiest way to find this out is to turn error_reporting on. Open your `php.ini` file and search for `error_reporting`. Set to `E_ALL`. If it is already set, remove the semicolon `;` at the beginning of the line (to remove the comment).

Comment: @KevinPaladin Don't know Kevin. I thought there was something I didn't know about. PHP seems to get trickier by the hour lol!

Comment: @user2475515 Try to execute your form from within the same folder and test it out from there. Might just be a `path` issue. On an added note, you're going to need `session_start();` in all affected/touched pages for sessions to work properly.

Comment: I made ;error_reporting to ->
E_ALL error_reporting
Where does it write errors?(Don't see any at site)

I also tried to move check.php to same folder than html file is. Also edited it to run from same direction. 
Doesnt seem to work even still...

Comment: try adding this line instead of the line you edited.

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

When you process the php file, the errors should be displayed on theat page (if any)

Comment: @user2475515 See my latest comment at the top of your question about `session_start`.

Comment: sorry, took while to answer...
added  session_start(); like u told me to. still does not work.

Added error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT to my PHP config file. It didn't write any errors to my check.php. After refreshing site. (If u meant that with process the php file)

Comment: ahh.. u need to restart apache after changing `php.ini`. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: The errors should be displayed on the browser, if encountered. Why don't post all the files' script in pastebin and give their references. Looks like it is the only way to find the problem.

Comment: Okay. I uploaded files to my SkyDrive. 

Here is link to you. https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=6854030AFCED54A7!114&authkey=!AJs92enZxMkkbOY

(Hope it works)

Comment: Well, when I ran the file `check.php` it displayed the following error info : `Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`.

I think there are many other errors too and so, I would suggest you to turn on error reporting first without which it is nearly impossible to find the cause, as it seems like the file `common.php` was not written by you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575482/php-how-do-i-enable-error-reporting